# How to create a button in an app that sets edit texts to 0 in java?

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext

I am creating a simple calculator that has 5 buttons, 2 edit texts and a textview, the user inputs a value for number1 then number 2 then presses eithor, add, subtract, multiply, divide or clear. The value is then shown in the textview. How can I get the clear button to remove the values for num1 and num 2? Here is what I have,

```
package com.example.moiz_.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView result;
EditText number1, number2;
Button add, subtract, divide, multiply, Clear;
float result_num;
float num1, num2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result);

    number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
    number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number2);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sum);
    subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Subtract);
    divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Divide);
    multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Multiply);
    Clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

            result_num = num1 + num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));

        }
    });

    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

            result_num = num1 - num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
        }
    });

    divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

            result_num = num1 / num2;

            result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
        }
    });

    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

            result_num = num1 * num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
        }
    });

    Clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());


            result.setText("0");
        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: number1.setText("");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an on click listener for the clear button and in the function write

```
number1.setText("0")
```

and same for number 2